# Compiling an rcc file is skipped with cmake --build, but works with make. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: qt, makefile, cmake, rcc

I have a larger project in which some *.qrc files are used and compiled using Qt's RCC.  The project is configured via CMake as a Unix Makefile project.
When I build the program via make everything works without problems, but when I build via Cmake --build the corresponding files are not compiled. Unfortunately, CMake does not produce any output describing the problem (-verbose option is set).  Does anyone have an idea what this could be? Could it be path variables? If so, how can I set them for the build process? What is the best way to debug such a problem?

To add the target I'm using qt5_add_binary_resources

The platform I am using is macOS.

Comment: drag and drop your cmake.txt file in qt creator and run and build cmake there , then you can see all errors .

Comment: Okay with qt creator it worked  The difference between the call I made and the one Qt Creator makes was the -j argument. Removing the -j option allowed a successful build from the terminal. Many thanks at this point!